# Push segue from custom uitableviewcell needs two clicks and does not work properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview with custom uitableviewcells. Trying to perform a segue from each cell, something strange happens.

I have traced the code with an NSLog to know what is happing (showing each cell textname), and if I click over a cell, the log is not showed, and If I click in other cell after , the logs displays the previously cell clicked textname.

Note that I have many sections created programmatically. So I have many Arrays, one for each section. The uitableview is into a container.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"Cell: %@",[opcionesEstado objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Cell: %@",[opcionesPersonajes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"Cell: %@",[opcionesNoticias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"Cell: %@",[opcionesAjustes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"Cell: %@",[opcionesLogout objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            break;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use **didDeselectRowAtIndexPath**. And you should use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: OMGG, stupid error. Thanks a lot! I havent seen it :)